# Rating in SPFx webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, rating

is there any way to show rating in spfx web part from list as star

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using React, you can use an NPM package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-ratings to do what you're looking for.

[image]

To use it:

1. Add the NPM package to your project by using:

```
npm i react-star-ratings
```

2. In your web part's component (where you render the content), add the following `import`:

```
import StarRatings from './react-star-ratings';
```

3. In your `render` method, add the star rating control and pass the average rating:

```
 <StarRatings
        rating={2.403}
      />
```

Let us know if you're not looking at using an NPM package, or if you aren't using React.

I hope this helps.

Comment: it worked , thank you